# Angular 4 feature module

Tags: javascript, angular

Can we have a angular 4 feature module developed in separate project and make a link with root module to work as lazy loading ?

if that so, what would be the routing url for loadChildren property

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Follow [this](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/how-to-build-and-publish-an-angular-module-7ad19c0b4464) guide and check out official Angular modules like `HttpModule`.

### Long Answer

This is possible but I haven't found any official documentation or tutorial about it. What you basically have to do is to create a library that can be included in your project. Like the official `RouterModule` or `HttpModule`.

You basically have to create a module, export all the public stuff like directives, services and components and then finally build the whole feature module.

Building the module isn't that simple. In the `HttpModule` they use **ngc** for compiling the typescript. **ngc** is the official Angular compiler. Afterwards, they package and minify their code with **rollup-js** and **minify-js**.

So the dependencies you need (for the most basic library) are `@angular/core`, `@angular/compiler`, `@angular/compiler-cli`, `rollup`, `rxjs`, `typescript` and `zone.js`.

You also have to modify your `tsconfig.json`.
These are the major changes (the second link I provided at the end lists more performance boosting changes):

- add the following line for Ahead-of-Time (AoT) compilation:
  `"angularCompilerOptions": { "strictMetadataEmit": true}`
- set `"declaration": true`, this makes the compiler create the definitions file (you know the `some-file.d.ts` stuff)
- It's also important that you use explicit paths to other modules. This is because if you in example include the Angular modules in your build the application will crash because Angular would be present twice.
- also set `"module": "es2015"`

Now you need to configure the `rollup.config.js` like this:

- `entry` should be the path to your transpiled `index.ts`
- `dest` should be `bundles/modulename.umd.js`, this is the Angular standard name for modules (`.umd.js` is the standard format Angular modules).
- `moduleName` is going to be a JavaScript object so no special chars (also no dashes)
- at last, you have to define the globals, you know the modules you use but haven't written yourselves like `@angular/core`, so `globals` should be an object like this: `{ "@angular/core": "ng.core"}`

Take a look at Angular's `rollup.config.js` for the `HttpModule?`: [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/http/rollup.config.js).

Then setup your `package.json` to publish your module. Imporant is that you:

- set the `"version"` (remember to use [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/))
- add your `"peerDependencies"`
- set `"main"` to the path of your `.umd.js` file
- set `"module`" to your transpiled `index.js` file

Now you can build and then add your feature module as a dependency to your other projects and use your awsome stuff there.

Two good post for further information (although the second one isn't simple to understand):

[This post](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/shared-modules-di.html) explains how to create a (shared) module.

[This post](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/how-to-build-and-publish-an-angular-module-7ad19c0b4464) goes more into the little details about publishing your module.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a very good talk](https://youtu.be/unICbsPGFIA) on YouTube that will help you achieve that.
It covers the configuration from scratch without tons of dependencies and boilerplate code.